# Convert categorical data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with this type of data (too many columns):

```
col1        int64
col2        int64
col3        category
col4        category
col5        category
```

Columns look like this:

```
Name: col3, dtype: category
Categories (8, object): [B, C, E, G, H, N, S, W]
```

I want to convert all the values in each column to integer like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I solved this for one column by this:

```
dataframe['c'] = pandas.Categorical.from_array(dataframe.col3).codes
```

Now I have two columns in my dataframe - old `col3` and new `c` and need to drop old columns.

That's bad practice. It works but in my dataframe there are too many columns and I don't want do it manually.

How can I do this more cleverly?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

First, to convert a Categorical column to its numerical codes, you can do this easier with: `dataframe['c'].cat.codes`.
Further, it is possible to select automatically all columns with a certain dtype in a dataframe using `select_dtypes`. This way, you can apply above operation on multiple and automatically selected columns.

First making an example dataframe:

```
In [75]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab'),  'col3':list('ababb')})

In [76]: df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('category')

In [77]: df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype('category')

In [78]: df.dtypes
Out[78]:
col1       int64
col2    category
col3    category
dtype: object
```

Then by using `select_dtypes` to select the columns, and then applying `.cat.codes` on each of these columns, you can get the following result:

```
In [80]: cat_columns = df.select_dtypes(['category']).columns

In [81]: cat_columns
Out[81]: Index([u'col2', u'col3'], dtype='object')

In [83]: df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     0     0
1     2     1     1
2     3     2     0
3     4     0     1
4     5     1     1
```

Note:

1. NaN becomes -1
2. This method is fast because the relationship between code and category is readily available and do not need to be computed.

Comment: is there a easy way we get a mapping between category code and category string values?

Comment: You can use:  `df['col2'].cat.categories` for instance.

Comment: Pointing out for anyone concerned that this will map `NaN`'s uniquely to `-1`

Comment: Love the 2 liners ;)

Comment: Watch out that if the categorical is ordered (an ordinal) then the numerical codes returned by `cat.codes` may NOT be the ones you see in the Series !

Comment: In this example `col1` and `col2` will be the same and this may NOT be what you want:  ```df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':[5,4,3,2,1],  'col3':list('ababb')})
df.col1 = df.col1.astype('category', ordered=False)
df.col2 = df.col2.astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=[5,4,3,2,1], ordered=True))```

Comment: The code in my answer works exactly the same for ordered or non-ordered categoricals.

Comment: I tried to convert directly one column with _df[''col2'] = _df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes) but I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'
` even though the column is a categorical type.

Answer (score 89):

This works for me:

```
pandas.factorize( ['B', 'C', 'D', 'B'] )[0]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: great, much simpler than the accepted answer

Comment: I agree, this is a very good and efficient answer

Comment: best answer, imho

Comment: While this solves the problem, you should prefer the accessor `pd.Series.cat.codes` over `pd.factorize` for performance reasons. Internally, a categorical is already a list of indices and extracting that via `.cat.codes` takes `O(0)` time, whereas (re-)factorizing via `pd.factorize` takes `O(n)` time ([currently](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d17d73be969a7d004a7e1035afbf811a8fbf18a/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L634-L812) no fast-path for categorical).

Comment: Then, nowadays what should we use, pd.factorize(), astype('category') or pd.Categorical()?

Answer (score 26):

If your concern was only that you making a extra column and deleting it later, just dun use a new column at the first place.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab'),  'col3':list('ababb')})
dataframe.col3 = pd.Categorical.from_array(dataframe.col3).codes
```

You are done. Now as `Categorical.from_array` is deprecated, use `Categorical` directly

```
dataframe.col3 = pd.Categorical(dataframe.col3).codes
```

If you also need the mapping back from index to label, there is even better way for the same

```
dataframe.col3, mapping_index = pd.Series(dataframe.col3).factorize()
```

check below

```
print(dataframe)
print(mapping_index.get_loc("c"))
```

Answer (score 18):

Here multiple columns need to be converted. So, one approach i used is ..

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    if(df[col_name].dtype == 'object'):
        df[col_name]= df[col_name].astype('category')
        df[col_name] = df[col_name].cat.codes
```

This converts all string / object type columns to categorical. Then applies codes to each type of category.

Answer (score 17):

What I do is, I `replace` values.

Like this-

```py
df['col'].replace(to_replace=['category_1', 'category_2', 'category_3'], value=[1, 2, 3], inplace=True)
```

In this way, if the `col` column has categorical values, they get replaced by the numerical values.

Answer (score 9):

For converting categorical data in column *C* of dataset *data*, we need to do the following:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
labelencoder= LabelEncoder() #initializing an object of class LabelEncoder
data['C'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(data['C']) #fitting and transforming the desired categorical column.
```

Answer (score 8):

To convert all the columns in the Dataframe to numerical data:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
```

Comment: what is I have a column with 0/1/2 and I want to transform it into 'A', 'B', 'C' ?

Answer (score 5):

Answers here seem outdated. Pandas now has a [`factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html#pandas.factorize) function and you can create categories as:

```
df.col.factorize()
```

Function signature:

```
pandas.factorize(values, sort=False, na_sentinel=- 1, size_hint=None)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `.replace` as the following:

```
df['col3']=df['col3'].replace(['B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'N', 'S', 'W'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

or `.map`:

```
df['col3']=df['col3'].map({1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'E', 4:'G', 5:'H', 6:'N', 7:'S', 8:'W'})
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest ways to convert the categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables is to use [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) provided by pandas.
Say for example we have data in which `sex` is a categorical value (male & female)
and you need to convert it into a dummy/indicator here is how to do it.

```js
tranning_data = pd.read_csv("../titanic/train.csv")
features = ["Age", "Sex", ] //here sex is catagorical value
X_train = pd.get_dummies(tranning_data[features])
print(X_train)

Age Sex_female Sex_male
20    0          1
33    1          0
40    1          0
22    1          0
54    0          1
```

Comment: this is the exact pythonic way i was looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
categorical_columns =['sex','class','deck','alone']

for column in categorical_columns:
     df[column] = pd.factorize(df[column])[0]
```

Factorize will make each unique categorical data in a column into a specific number (from 0 to infinity).

Answer (score 1):

@Quickbeam2k1 ,see below                            -

```
dataset=pd.read_csv('Data2.csv')
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
X = dataset.iloc[:,:].values
```

Using sklearn [image]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder_X=LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
```

Comment: Why didn't you just correct your previous answer? Surprisingly, you are using `fit_transform` now instead of `transform_fit`and corrected the labelencoder definition. Why  do you use `iloc[:,:]`? this is useless. What is the reason behind the image? In case you wanted to prove me and @theGtknerd wrond you failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it less code like below :

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab'),'col3':list('ababb')})

f['col1'] =f['col1'].astype('category').cat.codes
f['col2'] =f['col2'].astype('category').cat.codes
f['col3'] =f['col3'].astype('category').cat.codes

f
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use manual matching:

```
dict = {'Non-Travel':0, 'Travel_Rarely':1, 'Travel_Frequently':2}

df['BusinessTravel'] = df['BusinessTravel'].apply(lambda x: dict.get(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a certain column, if you don't care about the ordering, use this

```
df['col1_num'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: np.where(df['col1'].unique()==x)[0][0])
```

If you care about the ordering, specify them as a list and use this

```
df['col1_num'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: ['first', 'second', 'third'].index(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
df['Grade'].replace(['A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2], inplace=True)
```

use the inplace argument if so that you dont perform a copy. you select a colume and replace the distinct there with the one you want.