# Best practice for converting object data type in pandas dataframe to categorical dynamically

Tags: python

I am trying to convert some `object` columns to categorical ones. Below is the `df`

```
CODE    ZONE    ZCLA    AMNT
1001     EC      M      200
1002     NW      G      100
1003     SE      N      150
1004     SC      G      200
1005     EC      M      100
```

So column `ZONE` and `ZCLA` should be *encoded* and the resultant dataframe will look like

```
CODE    ZONE    ZCLA    AMNT
1001     0       0      200
1002     1       1      100
1003     2       2      150
1004     3       0      200
1005     0       1      100
```

There are three approaches I am following to achieve the same.

Approach 1:

```
for cl in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
    df[cl],_ = pd.factorize(df[cl])
```

Approach 2:

```
for cl in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
    df[cl] = df[cl].astype('category')
    df[cl] = df[cl].apply(lambda x : x.cat.codes)
```

Approach 3:

```
le=LabelEncoder()
for cl in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
    df[cl] = df[cl].astype('category')
    df[cl] = df[cl].apply(le.fit_transform())
```

Approach 1 is creating a label -1 which I don't want.

Approach 2 is giving me an Error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cat'`

Approach 3 is giving an Error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Can any one please through some light on this? Am I missing out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can try to share some insight I gained having the same problem.
What I found is that to run the lambda function `lambda x : x.cat.codes` you cannot select the column directly even if it is a category dtypes.

The way to do it to select the column with `cat_columns = df.select_dtypes(['category']).columns`

Follow my implementation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab'),  'col3':list('ababb')})

def __pd_to_cat_trans(df, column_name):
       print("Create the Label DataFrame")
       df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype('category')
       df_label = pd.DataFrame()
       df_label['Label'] = df[column_name]
       df_label['Cat_value'] = df[column_name].cat.codes
       print("Transform the column {} to a categorical value".format(column_name))
       df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype('category')
       cat_columns = df.select_dtypes(['category']).columns
       df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
       return df, df_label

orig_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab'),  'col3':list('ababb')})

a, b = __pd_to_cat_trans(orig_df, 'col2')
print(orig_df, "\n", a,"\n", b)

Create the Label DataFrame
Transform the column col2 to a categorical value
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    a    a
1     2    b    b
2     3    c    a
3     4    a    b
4     5    b    b 
    col1  col2 col3
0     1     0    a
1     2     1    b
2     3     2    a
3     4     0    b
4     5     1    b 
   Label  Cat_value
0     a          0
1     b          1
2     c          2
3     a          0
4     b          1
```

A related question can be found [Convert categorical data in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011359/convert-categorical-data-in-pandas-dataframe)