# Generate numbers based on strings

Tags: python

I want to generate numbers based on strings in a column within a dataframe. I want to create numbers to represent each unique string.

Below is an example and the desired outcome.

```
String  Desired outcome
   A    1
   A    1
   B    2
   C    3
   D    4
```

The code below doesn't work because it creates many columns.

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['String'])
```

Comment: What about using OrdinalEncoder from sklearn ?

Comment: You can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011359/convert-categorical-data-in-pandas-dataframe/32011969), use LabelEncoder, or use OrdinalEncoder as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ord()` function to get the ascii value of a character such as:

```
ord('A')
```

The above command returns 65. If you want the characters to start from one, a simple method like `ordFromOne(character)` works fine:

```
def ordFromOne(c):
    return ord(c) - 64
```

Then you just run that over each of your characters. If your example characters are actually strings you can of course just map the function:

```
map(ordFromOne, example)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about dataframes but you can get the desired outcome by doing:

```py
def char_to_number(c):
    return ord(c) - ord('A') + 1
```

Docs for [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)