# Python Pandas convert multiple string columns to specified integer values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows, some columns all have ratings like A,B,C,D.  I am trying to do some machine learning and would like to give the ratings certain values,
Like A=32,B=16,C=4,D=2.  I have read some post on using [factorize and labelEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011359/convert-categorical-data-in-pandas-dataframe/46186626)

I got a simple method to work (while trying to explain the problem) from the link, but would like to know how to use other methods, I don't know how to tell those methods to use certain values, they seem just to put their own values to the data.  The method below works if only a few columns need to be transformed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Studentid':['12','40','36'],
               'history':['A','C','C'],
               'math':['B','C','D'],
               'biology':['A','C','B']})

print(df)

    Studentid history math biology
0        12       A    B       A
1        40       C    C       C
2        36       C    D       B


df['history1'] = df['history'].replace(to_replace=['A', 'B', 'C','D'], value=[32, 16, 4,2])
df['math1'] = df['math'].replace(to_replace=['A', 'B', 'C','D'], value=[32, 16, 4,2])
df['biology1'] = df['biology'].replace(to_replace=['A', 'B', 'C','D'], value=[32, 16, 4,2])

    Studentid history math biology  history1  math1  biology1
0        12       A    B       A        32     16        32
1        40       C    A       C         4     32         4
2        36       C    D       B         4      2        16
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  Please consider also upvoting my answer (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).

Comment: Have done. I just got enough 'reputation' to have my upvotes show up.  Thanks, trying to implement your solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to transform a relatively large number of columns, probably you don't want to quote all the column names one by one in the program codes.  You can do it this way:

Assuming the column `Studentid` is not going to be transformed:

```
grade_map = {'A': 32, 'B': 16, 'C': 4, 'D': 2}

df_transformed = df.drop('Studentid', axis=1).replace(grade_map).add_suffix('1')
df = df.join(df_transformed)
```

We exclude the column `Studentid` in the transformation by dropping the column first by [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and then use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to translate the gradings. As such, we will never translate `Studentid` if in case the student id contains the characters same as the gradings.  We add suffix `1` to all transformed columns by using [`.add_suffix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html)

After the transformation, we join the original dataframe with these transformed columns by using [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  Studentid history math biology  history1  math1  biology1
0        12       A    B       A        32     16        32
1        40       C    C       C         4      4         4
2        36       C    D       B         4      2        16
```

Comment: Well, Python weirdness continues...the code works in 'jupyter lab', but not in Pycharm, both systems using the same venv.  Problem is my code is mainly in Pycharm.....

Comment: @newoptionz  The codes are just general Pandas codes that make no assumption on the IDE.  What's the error message you get ?

Comment: Thanks, after a restart tonight, it was working in PyCharm.